# Question on UWP DataGrid data binding using MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp

For the first time trying to use [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) to bind data in a .NET app. Coming from a legacy .NET world, I'm not quite understanding the [use of `MVVM` in a `UWP` app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-and-mvvm).

I'm trying to bind following `DataGrid` control in my UWP app with my `MVVM` (shown below)  that is a class created on the top level of the project named `My_UWP_Project`. **Question**: To populate customer data, what value should I add to `????` of `ItemsSource="{x:Bind ????}"` line of DataGrid control?

**Remark**: For data binding, I'm using new approach recommended by Microsoft [{x:Bind} markup extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension) as apposed to [Binding class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding).

**DataGrid control in MainPage.xaml**:

```
<controls:DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" 
    Height="600" Margin="12"
    AutoGenerateColumns="True"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ????" />
```

**Customer class** [ViewModel]:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace My_UWP_Project
{
    //backing data source
    public class Customer
    {
        public String FirstName { get; set; }
        public String LastName { get; set; }
        public String Address { get; set; }
        public Boolean IsNew { get; set; }

        public Customer(String firstName, String lastName,
            String address, Boolean isNew)
        {
            this.FirstName = firstName;
            this.LastName = lastName;
            this.Address = address;
            this.IsNew = isNew;
        }

        public static List<Customer> Customers()
        {
            return new List<Customer>(new Customer[4] {
            new Customer("A.", "Zero",
                "12 North Third Street, Apartment 45",
                false),
            new Customer("B.", "One",
                "34 West Fifth Street, Apartment 67",
                false),
            new Customer("C.", "Two",
                "56 East Seventh Street, Apartment 89",
                true),
            new Customer("D.", "Three",
                "78 South Ninth Street, Apartment 10",
                true)
        });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `{x:bind}` will use codebehind as datacontext automatically. In your scenario, you are showing the control in mainpage, so you need to defined a `list<Customer>` object in your mainpage as a property of the mainpage. Then the you could use `ItemsSource="{x:Bind name-of-list}"`

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while I don't develop UWP apps but as I remember you can directly bind viewmodel's property or method with `x:Bind` approach.

First define the your viewmodel

```
<Page.DataContext>
  <Customer x:Name="ViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>
```

and then use it on binding.

```
ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Customers}"
```

Comment: `{x:Bind} extension` does not use `DataContext`. Please see the `x:Bind & Binding Default behavior` section of [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1218367/UWP-Binding-vs-XBind) article.

Comment: Weird, I just have an app that I used x:Bind with DataContext. That's maybe because of the template I use I don't know but I have no instance of ViewModel at codebehind of it. It's empty.